# How to show badge numbers on iOS app icon in xamarin cross-plotform application using c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am developing an xamarin CrossPlotform application in which i have to show the number of notification count on the iOS application icon. Please provide if any way to do this.

Comment: https://github.com/alexrainman/Badge

Comment: Thanks Jason for quick reply, can you please suggest me a step by step procedure if you have any

Comment: read the docs - it is literally one line of code

Comment: Thanks Jason, i have placed  "CrossBadge.Current.SetBadge(10);" this line of code in AppDelegeate.cs file.

Can i test this with Mac simulator or need any external iOS  Device to test this

Comment: Hi, have you solved it?

Comment: No Cole Xia, Looking for a solution